# Calculate Age based on DOB

Tags: datastage

I am using IBM DataStage
Below is transformer stage expression, where I have date from `Link_4.DOB` with format of `%yyyy%mm%dd (20231221)`. I want to calculate the age:

Below is my simple try, but it's not an accurate DOB

```
YearFromDate(CurrentDate()) - YearFromDate(StringToDate(Link_4.DOB, "%yyyy%mm%dd"))
```

Is it possible to calculate the exact age based on the expression supported by DataStage?

Answer (score 0):

Use your approach (your_result) and add a logic to compare month and days additionally.

Pseudo code

```
IF YearFromDate(CurrentDate()) : Link_4.DOB[5,4] < CurrentDate() 
THEN your_result - 1
ELSE your_result
```

This will build this years birthdays and compare it to the current date.
If the current date is smaller than this years birthday your year-logic will be corrected by -1.